# I just earned Mortarboard from a bounty refund given last year

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, bounties, daily-reputation-badges

[The question in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92469/135887).

I placed a bounty on it, and it was refunded back in May of 2011.  Today it shows up on my Reputation tab as a total rep earning of 212 for the day.  It's the only time I've ever hit the rep cap here on meta.

Now, I'm not sure if that should be considered rep earning or not, but I seriously don't think it should qualify for Mortarboard.  The badge was issued either on the date or retroactive to the date that the bounty was refunded, and the notification simply went out now.

Comment: That's weird, the question itself doesn't have any traces that the bounty ever existed. Is that normal behavior for refunded bounties?

Comment: @animuson It is, yeah.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea as to why I got this badge, but I bet the cause is the same. +1

Comment: When you say you just got it, you just got notified today? Looking at your badge history, it does say you were awarded that badge back on May 31, 2011...

Comment: I was *notified* of it this afternoon.

Comment: @Charles I see Stack uses Australia Post for their badge notifications...

Comment: The fact that several people received the badge today (and possibly for things long past) is by design; the Mortarboard badge query was tweaked yesterday to be more accurate, so you would expect this to happen. However, that a bounty refund would count here -- I wouldn't assume that's intentional :)

Comment: I also got it from a refunded bounty, but got the notification right away (You can see the rep Refund on 25th July - though I am not able to see the date on the badge)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated the Mortarboard query to use our newer RepHistory table, which is a more efficient and correct* way to find matching users.  However, I didn't filter that particular bounty cancelled event from the criteria.

This has been fixed and the erroneous badges removed from all sites.

<sup>* previous calculation did not factor in the 2 rep awarded for accepting an answer.</sup>