# I've just been notified that I've been awarded the mortarboard badge for 10 rep?

Tags: support, badges, notifications, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I just earned Mortarboard from a bounty refund given last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146874/i-just-earned-mortarboard-from-a-bounty-refund-given-last-year)

I've just visited SO and apparently I've been awarded the mortarboard rep. The problem is I've had 1 upvote in the last 24 hours. I think there's a bug here.

EDIT: as some have commented I may have had it for some time. 
But I got a notification today. Out of the blue.

Comment: You've had it for a long time. You probably didn't notice it until now.

Comment: If you order your badges by "recent" you will notice it's by far not the first badge on the list.

Comment: i has just popped up in my notifications

Comment: Strange, because it seems to have been awarded on June 19th 2009. We're talking SO here, right? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1116/john-nolan?tab=activity&sort=all&page=49)

Comment: yeah I got a notification today though.

Comment: [The fact that several people received the badge today (and possibly for things long past) is by design; the Mortarboard badge query was tweaked yesterday to be more accurate, so you would expect this to happen. – balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146874/i-just-earned-mortarboard-from-a-bounty-refund-given-last-year#comment421133_146874)